# How to get digicert high assurance in my Mac

Tags: ssl, certificate, https, keychain

I removed Digicert high assurance certificate from the keychain. Now when I visit facebook.com or other ssl websites from chrome, they don't open and I get an SSL error, e.g.:

[image]

How can I to get those certificates back in my mac?

Answer (score 0):

You can download the Digicert root certificates from https://www.digicert.com/digicert-root-certificates.htm. Once you import them everything should work fine again.